# Using withmock with Gingko and Gomega

Tags: go

Is it possible to use both withmock and Ginkgo in the same suite of Golang tests?

We've tried to run `withmock ginkgo -r` to run our tests, but it appears that withmock is polluting the namespace of the current block, presumably by doing 'dot imports' under the hood.

We get errors similar to the following:

```
.../broker/broker_suite_test.go:7: EXPECT redeclared during import "github.com/onsi/gomega"
    previous declaration during import "github.com/onsi/ginkgo"
```